# How to get munin to monitor and show CPU temperatures

Tags: cpu, temperature, monitoring, munin

**Ubuntu 18.04 system has kernel module `coretemp` kernel module installed:**

```
% lsmod | grep coretemp
coretemp               20480  0
```

**It also has command-line utilities `lm-sensors` to check temperatures installed:**

```
% which sensors
/usr/bin/sensors

% dpkg -S /usr/bin/sensors
lm-sensors: /usr/bin/sensors
```

**Calling `sensors` works + shows all temperatures (package + 4 CPU core temps):**

```
% sensors
coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Package id 0: +44.0°C (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C) ALARM (CRIT)
Core 0:    +42.0°C (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C) ALARM (CRIT)
Core 1:    +41.0°C (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C) ALARM (CRIT)
Core 2:    +44.0°C (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C) ALARM (CRIT)
Core 3:    +41.0°C (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C) ALARM (CRIT)
```

**However, looking at `munin` output in my browser, I see only the HDD temperature chart:**

[image]

#### How can I make `munin` also monitor & display the CPU core temperatures?

**things I tried (which didn't help)**

```
% sudo munin-node-configure

% sudo ln -s /usr/share/munin/plugins/sensors_ /etc/munin/plugins/sensors_temp
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution by digging into details and looking at the source code. Answer for the benefit of future users.

#### Make sure plugin output matches supported regexes

Looking at the plugin implementation: `/usr/share/munin/plugins/sensors_` I noticed that the plugin has detailed regexes in a (perl) global hash called `%config`.  There are 4 supported sensor categories:

- fan (Fan speeds in RPM)
- temp (Temperature in Celsius)
- volt (Voltage in Volts)
- power (Power in Watts)

Since the regexes are very specific, it is important to make sure that the output of the `sensors` command-line utility, matches these regexes exactly.  You cannot call `sensors -u` when the `munin` plugin expects output in the format generated by `sensors` (without the `-u` option).

#### Make sure symlink name matches a `sensors` category

The *name* of the symlink from `/etc/munin/plugins` to `/usr/share/munin/plugins/sensors_` must match a supported category. The category name is used as the `%config` key which defines each regex. Extensions like `fan` or `temp`, which match a supported category are good:

```
sensors_fan -> /usr/share/munin/plugins/sensors_
sensors_temp -> /usr/share/munin/plugins/sensors_
```

But using `tmp` or `cpu_temp` instead of `temp` will not work.

#### Restart the `munin-node` service

Another detail that I missed, was the need to restart the `munin-node` service after every change in configuration or adding a plugin symlink:

```
sudo systemctl restart munin-node
```

#### Remove empty charts of unsupported/missing devices

If you see empty graphs for non-existent devices. It is also recommended to remove reports on non-exiting devices:

```
munin-node-configure --suggest --remove-also --shell | bash
```

#### Result

Now `munin` shows all my CPU + other system temperatures:

[image: weekly temperatures chart]